# Ruby: How to use array names stored in array

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I am trying to cycle through all possible combinations of values stored in several arrays. To do this, I decided to put the array names into an array, then use permutation to build all possible combinations of the arrays, with the idea being I would then use the array-stored array names in an '.each do'

```
$arrays = ["$array1", "$array2", "$array3"]

$arrays.permutation(3).each do |val1,val2,val3|
  val1.each do |step|
    ...check
      val2.each do |step2|
        ...check2
          val3.each do |step3|
            ...check3
           end
       end
    end
 end
```

However, you can't pass in an array name as a string. How can I make it work?

Comment: That you are using global variables for your array names has bad code smell. It would be good to learn how variables are scoped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reference the arrays directly (instead of using strings that contain their variable names):

```ruby
$arrays = [$array1, $array2, $array3]
```

Comment: ha! why didn't I think of that! Thank you!

Comment: @WillVonWizzlepig: you're welcome =)  Feel free to upvote and/or accept if you think this answer solves it.